# How to display .swf flash files in C# Windows Forms desktop application?

Tags: c#, winforms, flash

My app is about categorizing and describing .swf files stored on my disc, so my main functionality should be to preview the files. How can I play flash files in my Windows Forms desktop app? I'm using visual studio 2010 premium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will see if I can find the full documentation and examples, but there are COM wrappers named axshockwaveflash

Here is a general link that might help guide you:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/5815e676-50b0-47f4-964a-c1bcebfdb9a4/

Here is another: http://www.programmingforums.org/post164816.html

Comment: Thank you, but my main problem now is - what I need to import/include to my project before I will initalize these objects?

Comment: Try this: http://fci-h.blogspot.com/2007/06/how-to-play-flash-swf-inside-c.html?m=1