# Shockwave Object (C# Winform)

Tags: c#, winforms, flash, visual-studio-2015

So I've added `Shockwave Flash Object` to my windows form, how can I get it to play a swf file that I am hosting using a GitHub page? (The GitHub Page is set up with the swf and it works all fine and I can load the swf if I type `myuser.github.io/client/client.swf` into my browser, but I don't know how to get the swf to load it on the form) I've tried putting the URL as the `movie` in the `Shockwave Flash Object Properties` but the form doesn't load it.
`AxShockwaveFlashObjects.dll` was added to the references too. When I use `WebBrowser` and make the URL `myuser.github.io/client/client.swf` and it just crashes, when I use the `Shockwave Flash Object` and make the move my client url or even do something like

```
axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = @"C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/game.swf";
axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
```

it just simply doesn't load at all.

Comment: Have you taken a look at some questions like [how-to-play-swf-file-in-net-4-0-c-sharp-winforms-application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448325/how-to-play-swf-file-in-net-4-0-c-sharp-winforms-application) or [how-to-display-swf-flash-files-in-c-sharp-windows-forms-desktop-application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442543/how-to-display-swf-flash-files-in-c-sharp-windows-forms-desktop-application)?

Comment: Yeah, but I am trying to use web browser and making the url my github.io page with the /client/client.swf at the end of it (works fine on ym browser and i can play and everything) but it just crashes the form. I have Win10 and VS2015, doubt that affects it though? @KiroYakuza

Comment: Does it give you an error code, or does it simply stop responding?

Comment: Program stops responding. I use windows 10 and vs2015, if that matters. @KiroYakuza

Comment: It's hard to see what your problem is, without some relevant code snippets. Try looking at this [guide](http://deepak-sharma.net/2013/03/15/how-to-play-flash-in-windows-forms-application-using-c-shar/). Alternatively, you could use a `WebBrowser` object to navigate to the file and play it (included in the guide).